# unity C#- where is the right place to define list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a structure in my scene Like this, What I want to get first is all children under Building (test01,test02,test03), then iterate these children to find all sub-children, in this case(Cube01, Cube02. Cube03)

[image]

My code is:

```
List<GameObject> childrenItem = new List<GameObject>();
List<GameObject> firstChildren = new List<GameObject>();
List<GameObject> secondChildren = new List<GameObject>();

private List<GameObject> getChildren(GameObject parentRoot)
{
    childrenItem.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < parentRoot.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        childrenItem.Add(parentRoot.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
    }
    return childrenItem;
}

private void OnGUI()
{
    if(GUILayout.Button("Test"))
    {
        firstChildren = getChildren(GameObject.Find("Building"));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < firstChildren.Count; i++)
        {

            secondChildren = getChildren(GameObject.Find("Building" + "/" + firstChildren[i].name));
            Debug.Log(firstChildren.Count + firstChildren[i].name);
            Debug.Log(secondChildren.Count);
        }

    }
}
```

I think it suppose to output:

> 3test01 3
>
> 3test02 0
>
> 3test03 0

but it's actual output:

> 3Cube01 3
>
> Error NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance
> of an object

it seem after run this line, the value of ***secondChildren*** has been assigned to ***firstChildren***

```
secondChildren = getChildren(GameObject.Find("Building" + "/" + firstChildren[i].name));
```

But if I declare the ***childrenItem*** inside ***getChildren*** function, everything back to wrok. Why this happen? I am a noob wiht C#, if anything I'm missing like variable scope knowledge, please let me know, Thank You Guys!

```
private List<GameObject> getChildren(GameObject parentRoot)
{
    List<GameObject> childrenItem = new List<GameObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < parentRoot.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        childrenItem.Add(parentRoot.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
    }
    return childrenItem;
}
```

Comment: FYI that's the C# programming language, not the deprecated Unityscript language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getChildren()` is returning a reference to the list created and stored as the class variable `childrenItem`, so each time you call that function it's clearing that same list and filling it again. That reference is then assigned to the `firstChildren` and `secondChildren` variables (while the empty lists you originally initialised them with will be discarded and garbage collected assuming no other external references). `childrenItem` , `firstChildren` and `secondChildren` all end up pointing to the exact same list.

When you move the `new` declaration inside the `getChildren()` function, it's creating a new list each time that function is called, so it's not overwriting any existing list. Those new lists are then assigned to the `firstChildren` and `secondChildren` variables (meaning the `new List`s you originally initialised them with become obsolete).